# Find the number of pairs where the first element is divisible by second element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose, given some numbers

```
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
```

you have to find all pairs `(a, b)` where `a` appears in the list before `b`, and `a%b = 0`.

Here, such pairs are:

```
(8, 4), (8, 2), (6, 3), (6, 2), (4, 2)
```

Is there any better algorithm than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** ?

Comment: Is there any constraint? How large is each number?

Comment: each element is between 1 and 10^5

Comment: no, numbers can be any random order

Comment: I think it doesnt matter anyway, bc if we find a solution better than O(n^2) for the sorted case, then we found an improvement for the non-sorted case because we can sort the list on O(nlogn). That is why i deleted the question (before I saw your answer) :)

Comment: No, it cannot be done better than O(n^2), because the output size itself for [1,1,1,1...,1] is O(n^2). However, it can probably be done in O(nlogn + k) or O(n+k) using hashing, where k is the size of the output (which might be quadric itself)

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of pair or list all valid pairs?

Comment: @pham trung , number of valid pairs

Comment: Is not it a creating a "lattice" problem?

Comment: do you have the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can precompute a list of all divisors of the possible integers in the input = O(n^1.5)

After that iterate over the input, while keeping track of how much a number is worth (i.e. how many pairs it would form).

For every number in the input you'll need to iterator over all it's divisors, i.e. O(n^1.5)

So the total complexity is O(n^1.5) where n is the maximum of 100000 and the size of your input.

```
class Denominators {                                                        

    public static void main (String[] a) {                                  
        int maxValue = 100000;                                              
        int[] problemSet = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2};                           
        System.out.println (new Denominators().solve(problemSet, maxValue));
    }                                                                       


    int solve (int[] problemSet, int maxValue) {                            
        List<List<Integer>> divisors = divisors(maxValue);                  
        int[] values = new int[maxValue + 1];                               
        int result = 0;                                                     
        for (int i : problemSet) {                                          
            result += values[i];                                            
            for (int d : divisors.get(i)) {                                 
                values[d]++;                                                
            }                                                               
        }                                                                   
        return result;                                                      
    }                                                                       


    private List<List<Integer>> divisors (int until) {                      
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();                     
        for (int i = 0; i <= until; i++) {                                  
            result.add (new ArrayList<Integer>());                          
        }                                                                   
        for (int i = 1; i * i <= until; i++) {                              
            for (int j = i; j * i <= until ; j++) {                         
                result.get (i * j).add(i);                                  
                if (i != j) result.get (i * j).add(j);                      
            }                                                               
        }                                                                   
        return result;                                                      
    }                                                                       

}
```

Comment: "For every number in the input you'll need to iterator over all it's divisors, i.e. also O(n log n)." In fact a number can have much more than O(log n) divisors, so I think this is more like O(n^(1 + eps)) for some eps < 1/2. However, the highest number of divisors in the range 1..10^5 is 29 which is rather small

Comment: Oh actually it's 128, not 29, so you should consider that: http://oeis.org/A066150 Apparently n^(1/3) is a rather useful approximation of the number of divisors of n for small-ish n

Comment: @NiklasB., where did you find that "the highest number of divisors in the range 1..10^5 is 29", (FYI: no of divisors of 720 is 30)

Comment: @vish4071 See my comment above, it's actually 128. I also linked to the corresponding OEIS sequence

Comment: Sorry...Second comment didn't load.

Comment: ah yes I see now that O(n log n) is clearly wrong. Changed it to O(n ^ 1.5) as I can see that is an upper bound. Is it easy to show it's less then 1.5?

Comment: @Stef Yes in fact it's O(n^(1 + eps)) for all eps > 0. But you need *very* large n for this to show.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic programming this can be solved with complexity O(nlogn). Similar to coin denomination problem.

Please refer the following link for coin denomination problem solution
[Coin Denomination problem](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CS7800.12F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf)

Comment: This seems vague at best. How do you deal with duplicate values?

Comment: I cannot see how it is similar. Your proposed algorithm returns the best solution while the question needs all the possible results.